# Retain Multiple selection in datagrid on clicking a UI element

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

[image]

In this datagrid if i select multiple rows and click on that wheel button, selection gets lost.

I want to maintain this selection on clicking that button.
How can this be done.

Datagrid selection changed gets fired before Button click event.

Comment: Define the `SelectionMode` of DataGrid.

Comment: This has been already set as Extended but as soon as I click on button, selection gets lost

Comment: You should set to Multiple not extended. Extended works when shift key is pressed along with selection.

Comment: Only 2 options are available in  silverlight datagrid : single and extended

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is supported.

Documentation on extended says:

> InExtended mode, select multiple items by holding down the SHIFT key
> to extend the selection from an anchor point or the CTRL key to
> individually select additional items.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridselectionmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Check here for a possible workaround: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/582437/WPFplusDataGridpluswithplusSelectionMode-d-Mult